# How to export JDBC template result to excel sheet

Tags: java, sql, excel, oracle, spring-boot

PersonDAO.java:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> searchPersons(Person person)  
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    return result;
}
```

How to convert the data in the `result` to download as excel sheet.

Tried with Apache POI:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Person Detail");

Object[][] persons = {
    {"PersonNAmeA", 1001},
    {"PersonNAmeB", 1002},
    {"PersonNAmeC", 1003}, 
};

int rowCount = 0;

for (Object[] person : persona) {
Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

int columnCount = 0;

for (Object field : person) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
    if (field instanceof String) {
        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
    } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
    }
}

}


try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("PersonDetail.xlsx")) {
workbook.write(outputStream);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No error, but PersonDetail.xlsx has not been created. What could be wrong in the code.

Can anyone help on this issue.
Thanks

Comment: How about writing the resultset as a flat file e.g. CSV file? No APIs needed. Excel has the ability to convert Text to columns anyway

Comment: @jmcg. Thankyou for the suggestion. I have not tried, but just writing into a csv file will open as Excel file too?

Comment: yeah Excel can open a csv file. you can then use excel's text to column feature to arrange each data to it's corresponding column. check out this link http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel

Comment: Thankyou . I am trying with apache poi and can continue till now. I will try this too.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) or [JexcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). The later is more lightweight solution. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html) how to generate an excel sheet.

You can even generate a HTML table and serve it with HTTP headers:

```
Content-Type: application/msexcel
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NAMEOFWORKSHEET.xls
```

Then opened, browser will prompt to save a page as Excel document.

[How to format data in html](http://niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/basic-html-to-excel-formatting)

If you don't need to format your data consider writing to plain CSV stream.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin Pavlov. Does this create a view to user. I have a export button (after user select multiple row from the table in UI) which fetches more information(contains personal information)  on user selected data and this has to be exported and downloaded as excel.Meanwhile I tried Apache poi , edited the quesstion...

Comment: No, it doesn't. You'll need to create a controller and, optionally, a view. You should call a service/DAO from controller and create a simple html table in controller or delegate it to view.

Comment: Thanks. can I ask for the latest version of JexcelAPI maven dependency.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl

Now it is 2.6.12

Comment: Thankyou so much . I will try this solution